# html file 2 time browsed 3 time browsed when page is not refreshed

Tags: jquery

i have a link on that link i am browsing the input type file , i am using the ajax for file upload first time its working fine but  when next uploading performing then the new file displaying 2 times  or 3 time based on how many file i have browse in the previous (first) upload.I want to reset all when file posted to the wall with out page reload.

these are 
the html and java script code are below:-

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" style="display:none;" value="" />
<script>
    $('#applus').click(function(e) {
        $('#uploadfile').click();
        $('#photo_video').show();
        return false;
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#uploadfile").change(function(e) {
            $('#img_upload_process').show();
            var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");
            var filen = document.getElementById("uploadfile").value;
            var fff = file.files[0];
            formData = false;
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);
            if (file) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "upload.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(res) {
                        $('#responseimage').append(res);
                        var duplicateChk = {};
                        $('input[id]').each(function() {
                            if (duplicateChk.hasOwnProperty(this.id)) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            } else {
                                duplicateChk[this.id] = 'true';
                            }
                        });
                        $('#img_upload_process').hide();
                        $("#uploadfile").value("");
                        document.getElementById("myform").reset();
                        $("#myform")[0].reset();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try typing the command    pause   at the end of each link